# How to get Google Play Subscription notifications in cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get the response of the req.body of my notifications from Google Play Services in firebase cloud functions.

The notifications come through a webhook on subscription or cancellation.
Everything seems to be reporting fine.
I am getting something wrong with the response data? Because trying to get some field values logs undefined:

```
console.log(req.body.kind) // logs undefined
console.log(req.body.autoRenewing) // logs undefined
```

Below is supposed to be the req.body:

```
{
  "kind": string,
  "startTimeMillis": string,
  "expiryTimeMillis": string,
  "autoResumeTimeMillis": string,
  "autoRenewing": boolean,
  "priceCurrencyCode": string,
  "priceAmountMicros": string,
  "introductoryPriceInfo": {
    object (IntroductoryPriceInfo)
  },
  "countryCode": string,
  "developerPayload": string,
  "paymentState": integer,
  "cancelReason": integer,
  "userCancellationTimeMillis": string,
  "cancelSurveyResult": {
    object (SubscriptionCancelSurveyResult)
  },
  "orderId": string,
  "linkedPurchaseToken": string,
  "purchaseType": integer,
  "priceChange": {
    object (SubscriptionPriceChange)
  },
  "profileName": string,
  "emailAddress": string,
  "givenName": string,
  "familyName": string,
  "profileId": string,
  "acknowledgementState": integer,
  "externalAccountId": string,
  "promotionType": integer,
  "promotionCode": string,
  "obfuscatedExternalAccountId": string,
  "obfuscatedExternalProfileId": string
}
```

My webhook

```
export const googlePlayWebhook = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    const data = req.body;
    console.log('start response body google');
    console.log(data.autoRenewing);
..
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Some services serve JSON bodies using `text/plain` which means the body won't get parsed by the Functions Framework. If you log `console.log(req.body)` do you get the data you expect as a JSON string?

Comment: @samthecodingman I do get something like this "GooglePlayWebhook
```{ data:
7:13:17.505 PM
GooglePlayWebhook
{ message:
7:13:17.505 PM
GooglePlayWebhook
start response body google"```

Comment: What do you get when using both `console.log('Request body type: ', { contentType: req.get('Content-Type'), js: typeof req.body });` and `console.log('Has Pub/Sub like body: ', !!(req.body&&!req.body.context&&req.body.subscription&&req.body.message&&req.body.message.data&&req.body.message.messageId));`

Answer (score 0):

It should be `const data = req.data;` instead of `const data = req.body;`